# Hidden JDialog box

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Recently, our Java application was a bit slower than usual, we just ignored it, because we use cloud DB which is a bit slow sometimes.

I used to navigate to other windows by pressing (alt+tab) in the windows machine. One day I found many `JDialog` boxes are opened. When we click it, nothing happens and it is also not shown. Again, when I press alt+tab, it is still here.

If I kill the application all the dialog boxes vanish. Since our codebase is huge with 5000+ Java classes, we don't know how to find this dialog box.

Comment: See if you can demonstrate the behavior in a [mre].

Comment: This probably won't help the OP, but if you're responsible for a large 5,000 class Java application, mark every GUI panel and report with a unique identifier so you can instantly go to the correct classes when there's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a heap dump using jmap (jmap -dump:file=*filename* *PID*). after that you can see in the dump which of the JDialog remained in memory using the visual vm

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try my best to find it. Thanks to @Alexander